# Phrase parsing and trending

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, regex

So I am in the 'design' phase of a project for work (software support) and would like to gather the communities opinions, ideas, etc. before I get to far into the woods. Ultimately I am building a web page that is very similar to Twitter's Trending page. Here is a high level overview of how I will be using it:

Our support reps will be creating tickets for customers as they call in, the text of the ticket is capture in real time and sent to another server I will refer to as 'Hoss'. Once the data is received by Hoss, we begin to parse the text. The primary interest here is a textarea where the support rep types in a brief summary of the issue the customer is having. I want to take this information, parse it and display it on a webpage that lists 'trending' topics so managers can get a real time idea of what customers are calling in about.

Now the fun stuff and where I would like to get some direction...For this example. let's say the summary textarea contained the following:

> "Customer is getting an error when trying to install updates, "error
>   in update.exe"

Now that the Hoss server has this text it can begin to parse it. I am interested in capturing keywords for the trending feed. In this example, "error", "install", "update.exe". However, it is also important to capture/track keywords that appear together. Meaning, I can easily capture "error" and "install" and basically count how many times those words have appeared in any given time, but they will not give as much insight alone as they would together.

Again, I am at the very early stages of this project which is why I have not attached code examples, etc. Nothing is off limits at this point! Thank you in advance! After spending many many hours reading through posts, I've learned the power of this community and it is an invaluable resource!!!

Comment: If you have a list of keywords, simply split the text to an array, count word occurrences, and intersect with your word list to give you a sense of trend

Comment: @Mark - The tough part is not knowing what customers will call about. There are some keywords we could use, but we want to be dynamic and capture what customers are calling about regardless. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is getting into natural language processing which is quite a large area of study in itself.

Some thoughts that should put you in the right direction.

1. Define a stoplist. These words will be ignored. They should include words that have no meaning (is, of, a, when). as well as words that have little meaning because they are likely to appear in alot of tickets (customer).
2. Define synonyms, different words that mean the same thing. When tokenizing your strings, you can replace a matching word with the root word to reduce variance.
3. Index keywords in 1-3 keyword phrases. Then summarize and keep count of these occurrences.

This is probably something you will keep tweaking as more data becomes available.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, it is much larger than I described but I was hoping someone like yourself could read between the lines and fill in the blanks. Thank you for your inout, I am particularly intrigued by steps 2 and 3...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggesting going for a clustering server like Carrot2 (http://project.carrot2.org/) then passing the ticket contents or subject as documents. You can choose algorithms to work with. Once the clustering kicks in, you can get trending topics by counts of clusters. Carrot2 is java but there are helpful php examples (for sending docs and retrieving result and counts) available with the code that you can experiment with. It also has a REST api that you can use with php curl or guzzle (makes curl suck less).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had not thought of a model like this. I will have to read up on it...

Answer (score 0):

Well i would suggest you build an array of the common phrases you would like to watch out for, each time a feed is sent to Hoss, during your parsing, do a `preg_match()` on the feed or count the number of times your phrases appear and store in a db.

Say you have a array of ten words that you are watching out for `$support_words=array('word1','word2','word3', ...'wordn');` ,count the number of array items and do a loop to check the count. eg. `foreach($support_words as $words){$count = substr_count($feed_from_customer_reps, $word); // insert the word and count into the database here. or better still fetch word if exists from database, get the current count and add the new count to it. // }`

This is an untested code infact its more of a psuedocode that an actual program code. I hope you get the logic tho...let me know if yo not clear.

resources:[php substr_count manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Comment: Tanks for reply. Please see my comment on the question to Mark.